# Access appsettings.json file setting from the class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I know how to set `appsettings.json` file on web project.But can you tell me how to access that from the class library project ?

I can configure it as shown below on the web project.Then how can I access that values from the class library project ? Is that possible ?

```
public class MyConfig
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}

public class Startup 
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
    services.AddOptions();

    // Add our Config object so it can be injected
    services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration);
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<MyConfig> config;

    public HomeController(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index() => View(config.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the section and then bind it, change this

```
// Add our Config object so it can be injected
services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration);
```

TO

```
// Add our Config object so it can be injected
services.Configure<MyConfig>(option => Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig").Bind(option));
```

Then you will get values in `HomeController` or any other place where you inject this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly IOptions<MyConfig> config;

    public HomeController(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var value = config.Value.ApplicationName;
        var vars = config.Value.Version;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "MyConfig": {
    "ApplicationName": "My Application Name",
    "Version": 1
  }
}
```

[image]

**How we call this other then web project ?**

Asp.Net Core DI resolve all dependencies before creating controller. So,we can create an interface and implement it. Then We can inject it into controller and from there access the `appsettings.json` settings.

**ICategory.cs**

```
public interface ICategory
{
    IOptions<MyConfig> config;
    IQueryable<Categories> Get();
}
```

**Category.cs**

```
public class Category : ICategory
{
       private readonly IOptions<MyConfig> config;

       public Category(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
       {
            this.config = config;
       }
       public Categories Get(long id)
       {
            var value = config.Value.ApplicationName;
            var vars = config.Value.Version;
            return category;
      }
}
```

**CategoryController.cs**

```
public CategoriesController(ICategory category)
{
   this.category = category;
}
```

When we call `category.Get()` method we can access the `appsettings.json` settings in that method.

Register it in `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddTransient<ICategory, Category>();
```

Comment: can you show me how to inject it into another project's class file ? Yes we can do that it within the web project as you shown.But how can I do it withing another class library project ? under same solution where I have multiple class library projects.

Comment: I added an example please check.

Comment: @Ahmar...IOptions<MyConfig> config;, in the ICategory interface -- error...interfaces cannot contain fields

Comment: @Ahmar...  That interface is in my class library project and the DatabaseSettings class is in that project too.

Comment: I tried adding an image and the code, properly formatted, but couldnt figure out how to do that in a comment...    public interface IContextSettings
    {
        IOptions<DatabaseSettings> AppConfig;
        
    }   Getting an "Interfaces cannot contain fields" error message from the red squiggly under AppConfig

Comment: This does not explain how to inject an interface in a totally different project in  the same solution.

Comment: @Luke101 you can inject it in any project within same solution as I did it in controller.

Comment: @Ahmar No, you still did not answer this. If you use `app.config` you can use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` in **any** assembly that runs as part of the loaded application. Show how to do it with `appsettings.json` in the depended-on assembly